# How to change Bluetooth storage location in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have an application. It is used to send and receive files using Bluetooth. My problem is, i wish to change the default location to store the file using Bluetooth at runtime. Can you tell me, Is there any possibility for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to configure it up to Android 4.1 Jelly Bean:

With the included stock bluetooth receiver you cannot change the location as of now, because it's hard coded. You need a 3rd party app like Bluetooth file transfer which might be configurable here.

In ./packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/ you can see it.

Constants.java defines this:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_STORE_SUBDIR = "/bluetooth";
```

BluetoothOppReceiveFileInfo.java has no switch for the location:

```
File receiveFile = new File(uniqueFileName);
if (sDesiredStoragePath == null) {
    sDesiredStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
        Constants.DEFAULT_STORE_SUBDIR;
}
```